# Class typename doesn't work

Tags: c++, class, function, typename

Please tell me what's wrong at  code and what should I change to fix it (I get compilation error):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int MMAX = 1000001;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    inline bool comp(int &A, int &B) {
        if (A < B) return true;
        return false;
    }
template<typename _CompareFunction>
    struct myHeap { // min-heap
    _CompareFunction cmp;
    };
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

myHeap< comp > H;

int main() {

}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Edit:
Compilation error:

```
heap_minimal.cpp:19:15: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _CompareFunction> struct myHeap’
heap_minimal.cpp:19:15: error:   expected a type, got ‘comp’
heap_minimal.cpp:19:18: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

(compiled with C++11)

Comment: Put the code you're asking about here on this site.

Comment: Nobody is going to read a whole repository. Please place the code here and give us the errors it produces in order for us to help you. http://sscce.org/

Comment: and paste the compiler error too

Comment: I have edited the OP's post added the code, hope it's OK ...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not related to the error, but you can just `return A<B;`.

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myHeap< comp > H;
```

You should pass a type as template parameter, not a function. Change the declaration to the following:

```
myHeap<std::function<bool(int&, int&)>> H{comp};
```

Or

```
myHeap<decltype(comp)*> H{comp};
```

If you want to pass **only** template parameter(without passing function), you should declare class MyComp with overloaded `operator()`:

```
struct MyComp
{
    bool operator() (int &A, int &B)
    {
        // if (A < B) return true;
        // return false;
        return A < B;
    }
};
```

And then just pass as parameter:

```
myHeap<MyComp> H;
```

Comment: and then even the code won't work. Or not as he would expect.

Comment: Ok, but if you ever implemented an priority_queue, there you had **priority_queue<int, vector<int>, CompareFunction>** for example... I want the **CompareFunction** to work at me too. How do I implement this?

Comment: `CompareFunction` here is a class with overloaded `operator()`.

Comment: @Vlad `CompareFunction` can also be a non-member function, as in your example. You just need to pass the type of a function that takes two ints and returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that in template definition

```
template<typename _CompareFunction>
```

_CompareFunction is a *type*, but then you try to use comp *function* in it. But you need a type, so you can fix the error like so:

```
myHeap< bool (*)(int&, int&) > H;
```

that works because bool (*)(int&, int&) is a type of your comp function.
Alternatively, you can define your myHeap to take a function as template parameter

```
template <bool (*fun)(int&, int&)>
struct myHeap2 
{      
};
```

And then you can use it like this

```
myHeap2<comp> H2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define a type use "typedef bool (*comp)(int&, int&);" statement and then declare the class by pass the comp type as template parameter, like your code: myHeap< comp > H;